# Immediate exit of 'while' loop in C++

Tags: c++, while-loop, break

How do I exit a `while` loop immediately without going to the end of the block?

For example,

```
while (choice != 99)
{
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 99)
        //Exit here and don't get additional input
    cin>>gNum;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm willing to bet you that the answer is in your assigned reading.

Comment: @akappa, I'd agree, but hell, better to ask then not ask.

Comment: @David Bejar Remember the goal is to not just remove the Homework tag, but to edit the good questions and close / delete the bad ones.

Comment: The while would already break if the choice is 99. `while(choice != 99) { if(choice == 99) }`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use break?

```
while(choice!=99)
{
  cin>>choice;
  if (choice==99)
    break;
  cin>>gNum;
}
```

Comment: Assuming choice isn't 99 entering the loop -- which seems to be a possibility here -- the while loop could be simplified to "while(true)"

Comment: Yeah, and storing the results in an array might also be helpful ;)

Answer (score 10):

```
cin >> choice;
while(choice!=99) {
    cin>>gNum;
    cin >> choice
}
```

You don't need a break, in that case.

Comment: But, ew, you duplicated the stream extraction code.

Comment: so? To "not duplicate the code" is not a dogma you should follow in a religious way. In this case I find this solution more natural.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with duplicating 'cin'. It's actually more efficient than all other answers in this thread. Putting an if-statement inside the while-loop makes the loop perform twice as many checks.

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

Use *break*, as such:

```
while(choice!=99)
{
  cin>>choice;
  if (choice==99)
    break; //exit here and don't get additional input
  cin>>gNum;
}
```

This works for *for* loops also, and is the keyword for ending a switch clause. More info [here](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/keywords/break).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, break will work. However, you may find that many programmers prefer not to use it when possible, rather, use a conditional if statement to perform anything else in the loop (thus, not performing it and exiting the loop cleanly)

Something like this will achieve what you're looking for, without having to use a break.

```
while(choice!=99) {
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice != 99) {
        cin>>gNum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`break;`.

```
while(choice!=99)
{
   cin>>choice;
   if (choice==99)
       break;
   cin>>gNum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

hmm, `break` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
while(choice!=99)
{
  cin>>choice;
  if (choice==99)
    exit(0);
  cin>>gNum;
}
```

Trust me, that will exit the loop. If that doesn't work nothing will. Mind, this may not be what you want...

Comment: +1 lol Maybe throw in a ::ExitWindowsEx(EWX_SHUTDOWN | EWX_FORCE, 0) so the while loop is not restarted under any circumstances!

Answer (score 1):

Yah Im pretty sure you just put

```
    break;
```

right where you want it to exit

like

```
    if (variable == 1)
    {
    //do something
    }
    else
    {
    //exit
    break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
break;
```

Answer (score -2):

You should never use a break statement to exit a loop.
Of course you can do it, but that doesn't mean you should. 
It just isn't good programming practice.
The more elegant way to exit is the following:

```
while(choice!=99)
{
    cin>>choice;
    if (choice==99)
        //exit here and don't get additional input
    else
       cin>>gNum;
}
```

if choice is 99 there is nothing else to do and the loop terminates.