# How to terminate a function once a condition has been met

Tags: c++, c

description:

I have a file that follows this format: `number number number`, here are a few lines:

```
0 00 19
0 900000 949999
0 9500000 9999999
1 00 09
2 00 19
2 200 349
2 35000 39999
2 900000 949999
2 9500000 9999999
3 00 02
3 7000 8499
3 9500000 9999999
4 00 19
4 7000 8499
80 00 19
80 900000 999999
81 00 19
81 900000 999999
82 990000 999999
83 7000 8499
958 95000 99999
959 7000 8499
960 85000 99999
961 00 19
```

The first column represents `area`, the second represents `num1` and `num2`.

I have managed to store each column in its respective variable with so:

```
int isRegistered(FILE* fp, int area)
{
    int finished = 1;
    int scanned_area;
    char num1[7], num2[7];
    int rc = 1;

    rewind(fp);

    while (finished != EOF) {
        finished = fscanf(fp,"%d %s %s\n", &scanned_area, &num1, &num2);
    }
    return rc;
}
```

I KNOW I "shouldn't use fscanf" and shouldn't scan in using `%s`, but these are assignment specific and I can't change them.

Now I have all these numbers stored in their respective variables, first column of numbers are stored in `scanned_area`, second column in `num1`, and third column in `num2`.

**SCENARIO**

I have an area value of 1. How do I code it so that when scanned_area == 1, the function stops?

Comment: I'm removing the C++ tag as there is nothing specific to C++ in here. Feel free to revert if you feel necessary. Also, homework tag is deprecated.

Comment: What? This is a C++ specific question not C. This is a C++ assignment, and it is homework.

Comment: We don't see a line of C++ code though

Comment: The homework tag is in process of being eliminated.

Comment: @eveo there is nothing specific here for C++, i.e. `std::fstream`, and the homework tag is not allowed to be used anymore. You should have seen that in the tag wiki for the tag itself when you put it in your question.

Comment: i cant see scanned_area variable getting any value here and where is myAreaVal varaible ?

Comment: Would you know how to do it if you weren't worried about hitting the EOF? That is, are you asking how to use `while(scanned_area !=1)` (hint, hint), or are you asking how to combine *two* end conditions?

Comment: are you looking for a `break`?

Comment: @Rapptz-[here's what I was told](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142386/why-have-tag-edits-for-c-questions-that-dont-use-a-lick-of-c-been-denied) about that. Granted my edit wasn't sufficient but I think this shows what the idea behind not changing the `c++` tag is all about.

Comment: there is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872996/immediate-exit-while-loop-c

Comment: @C.Lang It says that you didn't correct all the issues. You just fixed the tag and didn't fix the body of the question. The body of the question doesn't mention C++ once, so it wasn't until the comment section that this was portrayed as "C++" code.

Comment: the title asks about how to leave the function, and obvious answer to the question would be to `return`.

Comment: @Rapptz: yeah I said that. I was referring more to the, IMO silly, comments suggesting that there's no harm in allowing someone who is using c but believes it's c++ to continue thinking that.

Comment: @Rapptz: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158450/retagging-c-questions-as-c-without-consulting-asker

Comment: @BenjaminLindley To be fair, I specifically said *Feel free to revert if you feel it is necessary*

Comment: @Rapptz: Still, the tag should be removed only at the request of the OP.  Feel free to present arguments in the comments to convince him that it should be removed.  But the decision should be left to him.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an area value of 1. How do I code it so that when scanned_area == 1, the function stops?

You can use `break` to get out of a loop:

```
while (condtion)
{
  // some code
  if (scanned_area == 1)
  {
     break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function to stop then just return an appropriate value, in your case return an integer. Once a function hits a return statement then the value is returned and nothing else is after it is executed.

Hope this helps :D