# How to fix do-while loop that will not terminate on quit choice

Tags: c++, validation, input, do-while

I am working on an assignment where a menu is displayed, and using a do-while loop, if the user enters 4, the function must terminate. Where have I messed up that the function continues running? (I have defined function factorial and superfactorial but they don't have any contents because I am not done.

I have tried adding an if statement that makes sure the user has not selected the quit option

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

//Function Prototypes
void ShowMenu();
int getValidUserInputPosNumGT0(int);
int Reverse(int);
int Factorial(int);
int Superfactorial(int);
int validateMenuChoice(int);

int main()
{
    int CHOICE, // Holds menu choice
        NUM; // User inputted number

    const int REVERSE = 1, //Menu choice 1 -> reverse function
            FACTORIAL = 2, //Menu choice 2 -> factorial function
            SUPERFACTORIAL = 3, //Menu choice 3 -> superfactorial function
            QUIT_CHOICE = 4; //Menu choice 4 -> quit program

    std::cout << "Welcome to the playing with numbers program!" << std::endl;
    do
    {
        ShowMenu();
        std::cin >> CHOICE;
        validateMenuChoice(CHOICE);
        std::cout << "Enter in a positive number greater than 0:  ";
        std::cin >> NUM;
        getValidUserInputPosNumGT0(NUM);

        if (CHOICE !=QUIT_CHOICE)
        {
            switch (CHOICE)
            {
                case REVERSE:
                    Reverse(NUM);
                case FACTORIAL:
                    Factorial(NUM);
                case SUPERFACTORIAL:
                    Superfactorial(NUM);
            }
        }

    }
    while (CHOICE !=QUIT_CHOICE);
    return 0;
}

int validateMenuChoice (int CHOICE)
{
    while (CHOICE < 1 || CHOICE > 4)
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter a valid menu choice:  \n";
        std::cin >> CHOICE;
    }
}


//Function to display the program menu
void ShowMenu()
    {
        std::cout << "1) Reverse Number\n"
                  << "2) Compute the factorial of a number\n"
                  << "3) Compute the superfactorial of a number\n"
                  << "4) Quit\n"
                  << "Select an option (1-4):  ";
    }

//Allows a user to enter in an integer and validated that the number is > 0
int getValidUserInputPosNumGT0 (int NUM)
    {
        while (NUM <= 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Please enter a positive number greater than 0: ";
            std::cin >> NUM;
        }
    }

//Takes a number as a value parameter and returns the reversed number
int Reverse (int NUM)
{
    std::cout << "The Reverse of "<< NUM << " is ";
    int reverse = 0, remainder;
    while (NUM != 0)
    {
        remainder = NUM % 10;
        reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
        NUM/=10;
    }
    std::cout << reverse << std::endl;
}

//takes a number as a value parameter and returns the factorial of the number
int Factorial (int NUM)
{

}

//takes a number as a value parameter and returns the Superfactorial of the number
int Superfactorial (int NUM)
{

}
```

when the user enters '4' the program should quit/terminate, however, it continues to run and prompts user for a number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Immediate exit of 'while' loop in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872996/immediate-exit-of-while-loop-in-c)

Comment: Change `validateMenuChoice` and `getValidUserInputPosNumGT0` from call by value to call by reference.

Comment: Move the 3 lines after `validateMenuChoice(CHOICE);` to inside the `if`.

Comment: Also you need `break`s in your `switch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that after you get the user option, no matter what they enter, you then immediately prompt them "Enter in a positive number greater than 0: ". After the prompt, they would enter the number and then the program goes through the if statement that only triggers if the option != QUIT_CHOICE, then it will check the while() information. So if they enter 4 to quit, it will ask them for an integer after that and then not run through the if statement because the user selected quit and then it would quit the program. In other words, your while loop still ends, but asks for that integer first.

In order to make your while loop ends after the user enters 4, you need to move your input-getting statements (the following three lines that are in your while loop) INSIDE of the if statement that moves on if the user option != QUIT_CHOICE. Then, after the user enters 4, everything else will be ignored and the while loop will be exited.

```
std::cout << "Enter in a positive number greater than 0:  ";
std::cin >> NUM;
getValidUserInputPosNumGT0(NUM);
```

Hope this helps!